# Mostrar diferencia de días en tabla Jquery

Tags: jquery

Intento editar el numero de días de la tabla al presionar el botón, hasta el momento funciona y saco la diferencias de días entre la fecha de la tabla y la fecha actual,  lo que no consigo es devolver el valor de días y colocarlo en su `td` correspondiente.

```js
function ContadorDias() {

  var d = new Date();
  var fechaActual = d.getDate() + "/" + "0" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();

  $("#tabla1").find("tbody").find("td").each(function() {

    //encuentra la fecha por su clase                                   
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "fecha") { //introduce función y devuelve el numero de días entre las dos fechas                
      total = CalcularDiasEntre($(this).text(), fechaActual);
      //no se como devolver el numero de días a el "td" correspondiente


    }

  });

}



function CalcularDiasEntre(date1, date2) {
  if (date1.indexOf("-") != -1) {
    date1 = date1.split("-");
  } else if (date1.indexOf("/") != -1) {
    date1 = date1.split("/");
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date2.indexOf("-") != -1) {
    date2 = date2.split("-");
  } else if (date2.indexOf("/") != -1) {
    date2 = date2.split("/");
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  if (parseInt(date1[0], 10) >= 1000) {
    var sDate = new Date(date1[0] + "/" + date1[1] + "/" + date1[2]);
  } else if (parseInt(date1[2], 10) >= 1000) {
    var sDate = new Date(date1[2] + "/" + date1[1] + "/" + date1[0]);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  if (parseInt(date2[0], 10) >= 1000) {
    var eDate = new Date(date2[0] + "/" + date2[1] + "/" + date2[2]);
  } else if (parseInt(date2[2], 10) >= 1000) {
    var eDate = new Date(date2[2] + "/" + date2[1] + "/" + date2[0]);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var daysApart = Math.abs(Math.ceil((sDate.getTime() - eDate.getTime()) / one_day));
  return daysApart;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="ContadorDias()" type="button"></button>

<table id="tabla1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Numero dias</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <!--tiene que cambiar por el numero de días entre la fecha y la fecha actual-->
      <td class="fecha">20/06/2017</td>
      
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="fecha">19/06/2017</td>
      
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="fecha">18/06/2017</td>
      
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Mi problema no es obtener el numero de días , eso lo coloque para entender de mejor forma el caso, lo que requiero es mostrar el resultado de días en el td correspondiente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que haría yo es:

- Obtener el padre del elemento actual
- Buscar el primer `td` para este caso
- agregar el texto al elemento

Entonces solo agregaría esto:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(total)
```

o bien

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(total)
```

Tu ejemplo funcionando

```js
function ContadorDias() {

  var d = new Date();
  var fechaActual = d.getDate() + "/" + "0" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();

  $("#tabla1").find("tbody").find("td").each(function() {
    //encuentra la fecha por su clase                                   
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "fecha") { //introduce función y devuelve el numero de días entre las dos fechas                
      total = CalcularDiasEntre($(this).text(), fechaActual);
      //primero nos regresamos hasta el padre
      //despues buscamos el primer td y anexamos el total
      
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(total)

    }

  });

}



function CalcularDiasEntre(date1, date2) {
  if (date1.indexOf("-") != -1) {
    date1 = date1.split("-");
  } else if (date1.indexOf("/") != -1) {
    date1 = date1.split("/");
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date2.indexOf("-") != -1) {
    date2 = date2.split("-");
  } else if (date2.indexOf("/") != -1) {
    date2 = date2.split("/");
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  if (parseInt(date1[0], 10) >= 1000) {
    var sDate = new Date(date1[0] + "/" + date1[1] + "/" + date1[2]);
  } else if (parseInt(date1[2], 10) >= 1000) {
    var sDate = new Date(date1[2] + "/" + date1[1] + "/" + date1[0]);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  if (parseInt(date2[0], 10) >= 1000) {
    var eDate = new Date(date2[0] + "/" + date2[1] + "/" + date2[2]);
  } else if (parseInt(date2[2], 10) >= 1000) {
    var eDate = new Date(date2[2] + "/" + date2[1] + "/" + date2[0]);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var daysApart = Math.abs(Math.ceil((sDate.getTime() - eDate.getTime()) / one_day));
  return daysApart;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="ContadorDias()" type="button"></button>

<table id="tabla1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Numero dias</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <!--tiene que cambiar por el numero de días entre la fecha y la fecha actual-->
      <td class="fecha">20/06/2017</td>
      <td>roja</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="fecha">19/06/2017</td>
      <td>Roja</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="fecha">18/06/2017</td>
      <td>verde</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias estimado esa era lo que me faltaba saludos !

Answer (score 0):

Un modo es poner un contenedor dentro del td y reemplazar html:

```
<tr> 
  <td><span class="dias"></span></td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Y en tu función:

```
$(.dias).html('valor del cálculo de días');
```

Espero que te sirva.